# Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have problem with line:

```
if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 1) navigation.navigate('DrawerNavigator')
```

i receive warning:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state. and my view is not render

but if `information.data.login == 0` and invoking is this line `if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 0) navigation.navigate('StackNavigator')` everything is ok and my view render.

Full code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { postDeviceid } from '../actions/deviceid';
import { ErrorScreen } from './ErrorScreen';
import { styles } from './AppScreen.style';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class AppScreen extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(postDeviceid());
  };

  render() {
    const { information, error, loading, navigation } = this.props;
    const isLoged = () => {
      if (loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      }
      if (error && error.status > 0) {
        return <ErrorScreen error={error}></ErrorScreen>
      } else {
      if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 0) navigation.navigate('StackNavigator')
      if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 1) navigation.navigate('DrawerNavigator')
      }
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoged()}
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ deviceid }) => ({
  information: deviceid.information,
  error: deviceid.error,
  loading: deviceid.loading
});

AppScreen.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  information: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppScreen);
```

Comment: You should not use setState or something similar in your render function, refer to this answer: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542218/6114081

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're calling a state transition (navigation.navigate) inside your render function. You want to call this when the component has mounted and then render. You can use your props to conditionally render. So for example, if the loading state of true is passed in, test for it and return your loading component inside the render method.

Keep your logic outside of the render method because it should be pure.

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.
>
> If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in
>   componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping
>   render() pure makes components easier to think about.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { postDeviceid } from "../actions/deviceid";
import { ErrorScreen } from "./ErrorScreen";
import { styles } from "./AppScreen.style";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class AppScreen extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(postDeviceid());
    this.isLoged();
  }

  isLoged = () => {
    const { information, navigation } = this.props;

    if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 0)
      navigation.navigate("StackNavigator");
    if (information && information.data && information.data.login == 1)
      navigation.navigate("DrawerNavigator");
  };

  render() {
    const { information, error, loading, navigation } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />;
    }
    if (error && error.status > 0) {
      return <ErrorScreen error={error} />;
    }

    return <View style={styles.container}>
    Youre page content
    </View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me, why in case of StackNavigator it is working? I mean, view is render but in case od DrawerNavigator, view is not render?